# Turn off jquery function when click outside div

Tags: jquery, function

I'm styling a form and have some jquery that I'm using for a custom select drop menu, it's meant to change the border color to black when it's clicked but when you click another input field it should reset back to gray, I have a toggle class setup for the normal input fields but because the select menu is heavily customized I'm having to just change the color with this code:

```
$('.select-selected').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid black');
});
```

Is there a way to add to this so that when you click again, or preferably click outside of `.select-selected` it resets the function and returns back to a gray border? Appreciate any help.

HTML:

```
<div class="custom-select" type="text" name="enquiry" style="width:100%;" style="max-width:100%;">
    <select class="input-select">
        <option value="0">Select Enquiry Type</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Added html but .select-selected is being added to the div by more javascript, can see the full code i'm using here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Comment: Does it need to be jquery? Sounds like CSS would make more sense... `.select-selected:focus { border:1px solid black; }`

Comment: sounds like work with the blur event could help

Comment: Your HTML does not have any element with class `select-selected`, so `$('.select-selected')` is going to return an empty collection.

Comment: Added HTML but there's a tonne more javascript that's adding the select-selected to the div which is why you can't see it there, is it possible to add a click off function to the jquery I provided? @freefaller the css doesn't work even with '!important'

Comment: Is it possible that your script is adding the `<select>` elements **after** the `$('.select-selected').on('click',function...)` binding has taken place?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a specific need for jQuery, I would suggest that you could do this purely with CSS...

```css
.input-select { border:1px solid red; }
.input-select:focus { border:1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div class="custom-select" type="text" name="enquiry" style="width:100%;" style="max-width:100%;">
    <select class="input-select">
        <option value="0">Select Enquiry Type</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Otherwise, if you do need to do it via jQuery, then you can use the `blur` event...

```js
$('.input-select').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid black');
}).on('blur', function(e) {
    $(this).css('border', '');
});
```

```css
.input-select { border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-select" type="text" name="enquiry" style="width:100%;" style="max-width:100%;">
    <select class="input-select">
        <option value="0">Select Enquiry Type</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I linked in the w3 page I followed to make the select box, the css in the w3 tutorial turns off default select box styling so that the custom one can work, so styling the <select> element doesn't work I don't think, I added your jQuery also but once the select box border turns black it still doesn't turn off when I click something outside the select box or another input field

Comment: @JTR - Sorry, I didn't register you were dealing with a custom-control. Without you providing an [mcve] that we can play with, we're going to struggle to figure out what's going on

Comment: Provided full exact code at the link in the question, thanks for working on it - just need to deactivate the function when I click outside the area that triggered it.